# Extracting until the last character in a string

Tags: r, string, substr

Consider this data:

```
str <- c("OTB_MCD_100-119_0_0", "PS_SPF_16-31_0_0", "PP_DR/>16-77")
```

How to make it into a string like this?

```
str
[1] "OTB_MCD" "PS_SPF" "PP_DR"
```

I tried substr, but it doesn't work when the characters are of different length.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you want to do, is the bit you want to remove *always* the bit after the hyphen?

Comment: You want to stop at the first digit (minus the last hyphen ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match zero or more `_` followed by 0 or more characters that are not alphabets (`[^A-Za-z]*`) until the end (`$`) of the string, replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("_*[^A-Za-z]*$", "", str)
#[1] "OTB_MCD" "PS_SPF"  "PP_DR"
```

Comment: Sorry, but it doesnt work: [1] "OTB_MCD"      "PS_SPF"       "PP_DR/>16-77"

Comment: @JeppeOlsen  Updated the post